# string compare greater than expression predicate

Tags: c#, .net, linq, predicate

i am creating a method that generates predicate to filter out items from list.

```
        MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.ColumnName);
        ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Text);
```

for contains

```
 private static MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"); 
 Expression.Call(member , containsMethod, constant);
```

for equals

```
Expression.Equal(member , constant);
```

now i need for greater than, less than but this comparison will be of two string so have to use CompareTo like  `string1.CompareTo(string2) > 0`;
i need this type of function so that i can use as above other functions.please help

Comment: why not just do (x=>x > y)

Comment: What is your end goal? Are you building an expression to do something like this? "this1">"this2"

Comment: my goal is to make a expression for greater then and less than for comparing two string fields so that i can call like Expression.Call(member , containsMethod, constant);

Comment: Something like this (using the static `string.Compare(string, string)`) - `Expression.LessThan(Expression.Call(typeof(string), "Compare", Type.EmptyTypes, member, constant), Expression.Constant(0))`

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks buddy